# Insert an Image into PDF file Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, pdf-generation

I have searched a lot of pages but haven't seen any good explanation for making image to pdf. Also there are many never answered question. So it's looks helpful to ask here. The app has 'Camera', 'Photo Library' and 'Create PDF' buttons. After taken/choosing picture I want to attach this image into pdf file by 'Create PDF' button

Main Storyboard:

[image: my scrreen]

ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var PhotoLibrary: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var Camera: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var ImageDisplay: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


//MARK: Photo Library Button Action
@IBAction func PhotoLibraryAction(sender: UIButton) {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary

    presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}




//MARK: Camera Button Action
@IBAction func CameraAction(sender: UIButton) {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.sourceType = .Camera

    presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}




//MARK: Adding Texts on Selected/Taken Image
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    if var image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        ImageDisplay.image = image

    }
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}




}
```

Comment: you can not do it directly. You need to convert pdf into image. Then you need to take it in imageView. After that the image you want to insert take it in another imageView. Then Simply capture screenShot. After that again convert it into pdf that's it.

Comment: it looks very complicated I think. I'm new on Swift so I'm not able to to it.

Comment: It can be done directly. See my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following function to convert your image into pdf

```
func createPdfFromView(imageView: UIImageView, saveToDocumentsWithFileName fileName: String)
{
    let pdfData = NSMutableData()
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, imageView.bounds, nil)
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()

    let pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    if (pdfContext == nil)
    {
        return
    }

    imageView.layer.renderInContext(pdfContext!)
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()

    if let documentDirectories: AnyObject = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).first
    {
        let documentsFileName = (documentDirectories as! String)  + ("/\myPDFImage.pdf")
        debugPrint(documentsFileName, terminator: "")
        pdfData.writeToFile(documentsFileName, atomically: true)
    }
}
```

I create pdf of a view, so I pass a UIView to this function. Pass your UIImageView to this function and it should work fine.

Comment: Perfect! I'm trying but couldn't pass UIImageView to this function. Can you please bear with me?

Comment: Sure, what issue or problem are you facing?

Comment: I see error here: _("/\self.job!.Id).pdf")_. The error is: _Value of type 'ViewController'_ has no member 'job'

Comment: That's just my implementation. I have images of jobs, and I save them using the job ID's. Change that part and replace it with a filename of your choice. Just make sure to put .pdf as extension after your filename

Comment: That's great. function created and how can I run it when I hit button? I'm doing __@IBAction func createPdfAction(sender: UIButton) {  }__ What I need to do?

Comment: Just call this function inside your IBAction. And pass it the UIImageView from which you want the pdf created. And please upvote and accept the answer if it helped

Comment: @ShayanJalil Can you help me out the same solution for UIImage objects I need to pass with Swift 4.2?